# Unable to make work angular-google-analytics in Ionic. Aborted execution due to exception

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework, google-analytics

I am trying to add google analytics to an Ionic project. I am trying with [angular-google-analytics](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-google-analytics) by @jujule

For testing purpose I just created a sidemenu project with Ionic CLI:

```
ionic start angular-google-analytics sidemenu
cd angular-google-analytics
bower install angular-google-analytics
```

In `index.html` added;

```
<script src="lib/angular-google-analytics/dist/angular-google-analytics.js"></script>
```

app.js:

````
angular.module('starter', [
  'ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'angular-google-analytics'
])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, Analytics, $location) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // [...]

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event) {
      console.log('Location changed to ' + $location.path());
      Analytics.trackPage($location.path());
    });
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, AnalyticsProvider) {
  AnalyticsProvider
    .setAccount('UA-XXXXXXXX-X')
    .logAllCalls(true) // Log all outbound calls to an in-memory array accessible via ```Analytics.log``` (default is false). This is useful for troubleshooting and seeing the order of calls with parameters
    .useAnalytics(true) // Use ga.js (classic) instead of analytics.js (universal). By default, universal analytics is used, unless this is called with a falsey value.
    .setHybridMobileSupport(true) // If set to a truthy value then each account object will disable protocol checking and all injected scripts will use the HTTPS protocol.
    .setPageEvent('$stateChangeSuccess') // Change the default page event name. Helpful when using ui-router, which fires $stateChangeSuccess instead of $routeChangeSuccess.
    .enterDebugMode(true); //Calling this method will enable debugging mode for Universal Analytics

  // Here routing ...
});
````

Once installed in an android and inspected with chrome I see this:

[image]

Please notice both

*Cookie write failed* and *Aborted execution due to exception: abort*

I think because those errors I don't see any data in google analytics:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [google-analytics-plugin](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin) if you are using ionic. It is working fine for me.

Add plugin to your project using following command

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin.git
```

Then you need to set up  Analytics tracker inside your app. I added this inside the app run. And this code should be inside the 'deviceready' handler.

```
 if (typeof ga !== "undefined") {
        ga.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXX-YY'); //Enter your google analytic ID here
    } else {
        console.log("Google Analytics Unavailable");
    }
```

After that add following code inside the pages you want to track.

```
  if (typeof ga !== "undefined") {
        ga.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXX-YY');
        ga.trackView("Name of your page");
    }
```

Hope this will help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Web-based Android apps built with Ionic don't support cookies. GA never sends anything out because the clientID is not set. To solve this you have to generate and store the clientID yourself.

So, if you don't want to use a plugin you can set it up like this:

```
var analyticsOptions = {
    tracker: 'UA-YOUR-TRACKING-ID',
    trackEvent: true
};

if(ionic.Platform.isAndroid()){
    var clientId = window.localStorage.GA_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY;
    if(!clientId){
        clientId = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999999999) + 1000000000);
        clientId = clientId+'.'+Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999999999) + 1000000000);

        window.localStorage.setItem('GA_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY', clientId);
    }

    analyticsOptions.fields = {
        storage: 'none',
        fields: clientId
    };
}
```